# Bootstrap design varies between cdn and local download

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a login page using bootstrap with this url:

> http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

the design was good. late on i decide to download the same css file and integrated to my app.. the design all varies.

what would be the problem? what i missing to download?

My offline has the folders as : font,css,js

here is the comparison images:

[image: Online screen]!
[image: Offline screen]

**my offline :
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/bootstrap-theme.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')**

but no luck!

Comment: its clear that CSS is not applied on your page.. make sure you are using the correct path.

Comment: No the pas this correct here, but i don't know the problem.

Comment: then make sure as per the given answer you are using bootstrap CSS file on the top (i.e. just before `<head>` tag) and then call other CSS files.

Comment: are you calling the CSS this way as you posted.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet/bootstrap.min.css" />`

Comment: We actually don't know which CSS file contains styles for which element, you have just provided a screenshot. To answer you we need to see the code you are using, it would be easier if you set up a demo on JsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

While this can happen if you downloaded a custom version of Bootstrap, by the look of your images it's evident you're using other CSS files besides Bootstrap, be sure to include it as well, and load it AFTER Bootstrap so it overrides any needed declaration

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to every one.. there is a typo in my stylesheet path: (not shtylesheet it is stylesheets)

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheet/bootstrap.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

Comment: I never seen to inlude the CSS file this way.

Comment: this is jade templating!

Comment: Dou you mean jade4j? If so, please add the proper tag to your post.